# Unable to accept integer value through EditText

Tags: java, android

I have been trying to accept two values, 1) inpval2 and 2) rate, through EditText. I have used the Integer class and parseInt() method along with

`android:digits="0123456789." 
 android:inputType="number"`
 attributes to convert accepted values as integers.

Here is the code:

```
package kk.currency;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class CurrencyActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

EditText inpval1;
EditText inpval2;
EditText rate;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

public void btnclick(View view)  {

        inpval1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.away);
        int v1 = Integer.parseInt(inpval1.getText().toString());

        inpval2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.home);
        int v2 = Integer.parseInt(inpval2.getText().toString());

        rate = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.rate);
        int r = Integer.parseInt(rate.getText().toString());  

        v1 = v2 * r;

    }

}
```

Now the problem is that when I click the button (onClick = "btnclick") the app stops working.

If I remove

```
int v1 = Integer.parseInt(inpval1.getText().toString());
int v2 = Integer.parseInt(inpval2.getText().toString());
int r = Integer.parseInt(rate.getText().toString());
```

the app does not crash upon the click of the button.

Here are the logcat errors:

```
> 05-17 02:59:04.676: D/gralloc_goldfish(869): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
05-17 02:59:13.907: D/AndroidRuntime(869): Shutting down VM
05-17 02:59:13.907: W/dalvikvm(869): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
05-17 02:59:13.946: E/AndroidRuntime(869): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-17 02:59:13.946: E/AndroidRuntime(869): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
05-17 02:59:13.946: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3044)
05-17 02:59:13.946: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
05-17 02:59:13.946: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
05-17 02:59:13.946: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
05-17 02:59:13.946: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-17 02:59:13.946: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-17 02:59:13.946: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-17 02:59:13.946: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-17 02:59:13.946: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-17 02:59:13.946: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-17 02:59:13.946: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-17 02:59:13.946: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-17 02:59:13.946: E/AndroidRuntime(869): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-17 02:59:13.946: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-17 02:59:13.946: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-17 02:59:13.946: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3039)
05-17 02:59:13.946: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  ... 11 more
05-17 02:59:13.946: E/AndroidRuntime(869): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
05-17 02:59:13.946: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
05-17 02:59:13.946: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:359)
05-17 02:59:13.946: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
05-17 02:59:13.946: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at kk.currency.CurrencyActivity.btnclick(CurrencyActivity.java:24)
05-17 02:59:13.946: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  ... 14 more
```

Can anyone please help me with this? I'm a beginner and have spent quite a lot of time on this to try find a solution.

Comment: You should check your LogCat view and see exactly what exception is being thrown and where. It will tell you the error and the exact line of code on which the error occurred. I would have to assume that either you've entered a value in one of the EditTexts that is not parseable -- not an integer, or left blank -- and therefore is throwing a NumberFormatException (or ParseException -- I forget which), or your EditText objects are null, meaning you have an XML error somewhere. Check the error log and post it here if you can't figure it out.

Comment: I can see that your number contains a dot at the end "0123456789."

Comment: @kcoppock Done! I have just put up the LogCat.
and sleiman- I'll remove the dot and check again.

Comment: @sleimanjneidi: That's normal to include; it's so that decimal numbers are allowed. Of course, it actually shouldn't be allowed if he's trying to parse only Integers.

Comment: @kcoppock You were correct! I was leaving a field blank. Thank You so much!

Comment: @kcoppock yes, and he is asking about integers parsing

Comment: @sleimanjneidi: Yes, you're right, I just wanted to clarify to him that it wasn't necessarily a typo, but that if he wants only integer values, it's unnecessary. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
05-17 02:59:13.946: E/AndroidRuntime(869): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "" 
05-17 02:59:13.946: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138) 
05-17 02:59:13.946: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:359) 
05-17 02:59:13.946: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332) 
05-17 02:59:13.946: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at kk.currency.CurrencyActivity.btnclick(CurrencyActivity.java:24) 
05-17 02:59:13.946: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  ... 14 more
```

The line `at kk.currency.CurrencyActivity.btnclick(CurrencyActivity.java:24)` tells you that in your CurrencyActivity.java file, on line 24, it's throwing a NumberFormatException because of an invalid int, which is the empty String "". This means you're clicking with one of your fields empty, and it's trying to parse "" as an integer and throwing an exception when it fails.

Comment: Thank you! 
But now the problem is that what if I want to leave the field blank, initially? 
See, it's basically a currency conversion app and I want the field left blank to be filled up with the converted amount after the click of the button. Any ideas?!

Comment: so check if the string can be converted to an integer (you can use try-catch if you want) and then decide what to do with errors. see this : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)

Comment: +1 Yup, I recommend you use try/catch. It lets you handle situations like that however you want. You can simply leave an empty catch block, or you can stop the operation and display an AlertDialog alerting the user to enter a value.

Answer (score 2):

You should post logcat errors so we can help you more.

There are 2 things that could potentially cause your crash:

1.) you can't parse your input as an integer (values out of range ? text being parsed? decimal values?)

or

2.) your findViewById calls are returning null and when you call `inpval1.getText().toString()` it is throwing a NullPointerException

Comment: Yes, basically this. Remember, just because you specify the input method as `number`, that does not mean that it actually contains a numeric value. It is still simply a String value that you will have to parse, and handle exceptions appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

```
String s1 = inpval1.getText().toString();
String s2 = inpval2.getText().toString();
String s3 = rate.getText().toString();

int v1=Integer.parseInt(s1);
int v2=Integer.parseInt(s2);
int r = Integer.parseInt(s3);
```