# java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with debugging my code. I'm getting `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""` error at line 88 which is `Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();`. I dont' understand how the `Calendar` instance can produce such error.

WakefulReceiverWorker.java:

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();   // <----- line 88
    long newStart = c.getTimeInMillis() + 300000;
    AlarmManager mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, randomInt, intent2,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, (newStart), pendingIntent);
```

logcat:

```
12-13 19:57:01.589    2070-2085/com.example.app W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
12-13 19:57:01.619    2070-2085/com.example.app W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
12-13 19:57:01.629    2070-2085/com.example.app W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:359)
12-13 19:57:01.639    2070-2085/com.example.app W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
12-13 19:57:01.639    2070-2085/com.example.app W/System.err﹕ at java.util.Calendar.getHwFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.java:807)
12-13 19:57:01.639    2070-2085/com.example.app W/System.err﹕ at java.util.Calendar.<init>(Calendar.java:745)
12-13 19:57:01.639    2070-2085/com.example.app W/System.err﹕ at java.util.GregorianCalendar.<init>(GregorianCalendar.java:338)
12-13 19:57:01.649    2070-2085/com.example.app W/System.err﹕ at java.util.GregorianCalendar.<init>(GregorianCalendar.java:239)
12-13 19:57:01.649    2070-2085/com.example.app W/System.err﹕ at java.util.Calendar.getInstance(Calendar.java:1086)
12-13 19:57:01.649    2070-2085/com.example.app W/System.err﹕ at com.example.app.WakefulReceiverWorker.onHandleIntent(WakefulReceiverWorker.java:88)
12-13 19:57:01.659    2070-2085/com.example.app W/System.err﹕ at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
12-13 19:57:01.659    2070-2085/com.example.app W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-13 19:57:01.659    2070-2085/com.example.app W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-13 19:57:01.659    2070-2085/com.example.app W/System.err﹕ at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

Comment: It's not another variable....it's an invalid date in the Calendar.

Comment: @Elliott Frisch No, variable c is unique in this class.

Comment: Try `c.setLenient(true);`. Also `java.util.Calendar c = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();`.

Comment: " Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); "    are you sure that is line 88?

Comment: This looks similar. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19684888/java-numberformatexception-in-simpledateformat-getdateinstance

Comment: Only two choices.  You've got your line numbers wrong (1.7k repm, unlikely ;) or there's a bug in the framework.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16936086/android-error-in-java-inputstreamreader-only-with-huawei-phone Another similar issue.

Comment: Which JDK version are you using? Hm. Seems this method doesn't even exist in the version I use (1.6.0_45 I think).

Comment: @peter.petrov It's 1.7.0_45

Comment: @peter.petrov The link to the issue You've posted above seem to be very similar to this as I also debug my app on the Huawei device :).

Comment: Calendar.getHwFirstDayOfWeek isn't a standard java.util.Calendar method. It could be a Huawei implementation bug. Mobile device vendors sometiems override the Android Framework code to work with their specific hardware. Seems like every search for getHwFirstDayOfWeek is an Android Huawei device...

Comment: Can we see some of the code before that line?

Comment: On what OS and on what device do you run this code? What VM do you use? I already asked the JDK version and got the answer. On Windows, with the Oracle JDK and JVM, there're no issues. I would try to download the exact sources which you're running, and try to locate this non-standard getHwFirstDayOfWeek method and see what happens there. Definitely we won't find anything in the standard Oracle Java SE sources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just tested the app on the Samsung Galaxy S3 (i9300) and the error is not present on this device. It seems that it is Huawei's software problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
```

Not sure why yours isn't working, but `Calendar` is an Abstract class, so it might work better if you try [GregorianCalendar](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html).

Comment: Calendar.getInstance() is not __unsafe__

Comment: Doesn't change anything.

Comment: new GregorianCalendar() assumes your users use Gregorian Calendars, but not every country/region uses it.

Answer (score 0):

Try instantiating your Calendar this way:

```
Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
System.out.println("Locale is : [" + locale + "]"); // make sure there is a default Locale
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(locale);
```

----- Update ------
If you go through the stack trace, it looks like this is the culprit:

```
12-13 19:57:01.639    2070-2085/com.example.app W/System.err﹕ at java.util.Calendar.getHwFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.java:807)
```

Because the next line in the stack trace starts parsing the integer, presumably the value returned by getHwFirstDayOfWeek().

Comment: You changed variable name, otherwise the code is the same as OP's. How does that help?