# Cannot catch NumberFormatException

Tags: java, android, exception, try-catch

I am getting a NumberFormatException in my Logcat output and I would like to supress it. Apparently this exception only happens on Huawei devices (which I happen to own). For some reason my catch() block isn't executing. Can somebody please help:

Specifically, I would like to know why my catch() code is not called.

```
Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
System.out.println("Locale is  : [" + locale + "]"); // make sure there is a default Locale

 System.out.printf( "==Before try{}\n" );

try
{
  System.out.printf( "---Line44\n" );
  Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(locale);
  System.out.printf( "---Line46\n" );
  SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
  System.out.printf( "---Line48\n" );
  String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
  System.out.printf( "---Line50\n" );
  System.out.printf( "Timestamp  : %s\n", formattedDate );
  System.out.printf( "---Line52\n" );
}
catch( java.lang.NumberFormatException e )
{
  // Ignore stupid exception - Huawei specific apparently..
  System.out.printf( "HUAWEI bug\n" );
}

System.out.printf( "==After Entire Block, Line60\n" );
```

For more information, the Huawei bug is mention [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20574141/java-lang-numberformatexception-invalid-int) but surely there must be something wrong with my try/catch statement?

Here is the exception dump:

```
10-01 11:07:53.402: I/System.out(1758): ==Before try{}
10-01 11:07:53.402: I/System.out(1758): ---Line44
10-01 11:07:53.432: W/System.err(1758): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
10-01 11:07:53.432: W/System.err(1758):     at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
10-01 11:07:53.432: W/System.err(1758):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:359)
10-01 11:07:53.432: W/System.err(1758):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
10-01 11:07:53.432: W/System.err(1758):     at java.util.Calendar.getHwFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.java:807)
10-01 11:07:53.432: W/System.err(1758):     at java.util.Calendar.<init>(Calendar.java:745)
10-01 11:07:53.432: W/System.err(1758):     at java.util.GregorianCalendar.<init>(GregorianCalendar.java:338)
10-01 11:07:53.442: W/System.err(1758):     at java.util.GregorianCalendar.<init>(GregorianCalendar.java:314)
10-01 11:07:53.442: W/System.err(1758):     at java.util.Calendar.getInstance(Calendar.java:1098)
10-01 11:07:53.442: W/System.err(1758):     at com.example.test.MyApplication.onCreate(MyApplication.java:45)
10-01 11:07:53.442: W/System.err(1758):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:969)
10-01 11:07:53.442: W/System.err(1758):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3954)
10-01 11:07:53.442: W/System.err(1758):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:123)
10-01 11:07:53.442: W/System.err(1758):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1185)
10-01 11:07:53.442: W/System.err(1758):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-01 11:07:53.442: W/System.err(1758):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-01 11:07:53.442: W/System.err(1758):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
10-01 11:07:53.442: W/System.err(1758):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-01 11:07:53.442: W/System.err(1758):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-01 11:07:53.442: W/System.err(1758):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
10-01 11:07:53.442: W/System.err(1758):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
10-01 11:07:53.442: W/System.err(1758):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-01 11:07:53.442: I/System.out(1758): ---Line46
10-01 11:07:53.452: I/System.out(1758): ---Line48
10-01 11:07:53.462: I/System.out(1758): ---Line50
10-01 11:07:53.462: I/System.out(1758): Timestamp  : 2014-10-01 11:07:53
10-01 11:07:53.462: I/System.out(1758): ---Line52
10-01 11:07:53.462: I/System.out(1758): ==After Entire Block, Line61
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20574141/java-lang-numberformatexception-invalid-int)

Comment: @Rick77: No, its not a possible duplicate. I want to execute the catch() block. That is my problem.

Comment: Just to confirm, that exception is definitely being thrown from the catch block shown (at line 44)?

What happens if you change the catch type to `Exception`?

Comment: @deyur: Yes, line 44 is definitely inside the try{} block. I just tried changing to Exception as you suggested and its not picking it up either. I'm not massively experiencedin Java but I thought I was doing the right thing.

Comment: Maybe check the manufacturer `String` and skip the block entirely? If it's a known bug, then it's a known bug.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: Even though I get an exception, the code still works. It still gets the date and time. I'm just wanting to remove the exception from the logcat thats all. Maybe I should just put up with it :-)

Comment: @Rick77: I don't think there's any need to flag it at all. I'm not actually worried about the cause of the problem. I'm more concerned about my (lack of) understanding where Java exception handling is concerned.

Comment: How can it die with an Exception on line 44, and then complete the method successfully?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: That is an excellent point! Hmm. I will add some debug and update the question in a few mins. It doesn't make sense does it? :)

Comment: @SparkyNZ: sorry, I tried to remove the flag (just I seem not to can...). As for the "understanding" part, you are doing it right (the catch block and everything): as the post I have mentioned suggests (sorry for the flag), it looks like a weird Huawei software problem. IMHO you might learn some interesting stuff about real world hardware/software issues delving on this problem more, possibly something to talk about in front of a beer with a couple of friends, but not much more...

Comment: @Rick77: It OK. The word beer put a smile on my face so I regard your comment as helpful. :)

Comment: It appears to entirely be in Huwaeii code - there's not much you can do about it.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: I have updated the code and the log. As you say - how can it work? Well.. obviously it could not have generated the exception if it did continue onto line 51 and 52. I guess the "exception" was actually caught at a lower level but that lower level printed out the stack trace on my behalf anyway? That being the case, it has already been caught and I won't be able to catch it? Yes? I'm beginning to think that this comment of mine is the answer - correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: lhasadad and you are probably right: the most likely (and less scary...) solution to the problem, is for the exception to be catch-ed from within the guts of huawei's implementation (which printed it, for some reason...): in this perspective the whole "bug" thing is for huawei to have forgot to remove a print (a debugging one, maybe), from the code...

Comment: @Rick77: Indeed. Thanks for the brainstorming session guys. I'll live with it. Definitely given me something to think about the next time I see an exception appear in a log - so its all good experience.

Comment: SlipperyNumberFormatException.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would check the source for the other items in the call stack.  seems like it might be possible that something else is catching and logging and returning without the exception to your code.  does the timestamp line show up in the output?

Comment: Yes, ElliotFrisch and I have just came to the same conclusion if you read our comments. This is the answer.